# Random text sent to my boyfriend

Tags: google

My boyfriend said he received a text from me. I never typed it or sent it to him or anyone else. It somehow randomly was sent to his phone but wasn't in my messages to him. How could this happen?

Comment: This could be literally anything. We don't have enough information to answer.

Comment: So what other information do you need?

Comment: Header information, more context, etc.

Comment: is it gibberish or messages that make sense?

Comment: The text sense except the last couple words, and it is similar to a text a sent him last week!

Comment: The text makes sense, is what I meant to say!

Comment: is there any record of this message in your phone?

Comment: No not in my phone, and I didn't write it or send it.

Answer (score 4):

There's not really any security on the `From` number on as SMS message. Most SMS apps are honest and put the sender's real number, but if you write your own app, you can put whatever number you want.

Here's [a random online free SMS site](http://www.sendanonymoussms.com) that lets you spoof the `From` number:

[image: screenshot of sendanonymoussms.com]